# My android device did not get new added table feild data after update my titanium android application

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have made an SQLite database with my Titanium Application. When I use it in my application(Titanium Alloy) it goes well.

Next when I have inserted a new field into my table with an SQLite manager,the new added field data doesn't appear in App after updating my App with newer version. This problem only happened with my android device, In IOS, Its working well.

How I should do for android titanium so that when I update an App it will Also update SQlite database by fetching newly Added field from database ?? If I uninstall current App and install App again then it will work fine but I don't want to uninstall An App. I just would like to update an App. Please comment your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Android while update application SQLite database will not overwrite. It will use old SQLiteDB, If you add any new field in DB application will fetch from old SQLiteDB.

To solve this issue:

- Use SQLite database version. If DB version is new means need to ALTER table in runtime.
- First version : 
  `db.execute('PRAGMA user_version = 1');`
- Second version : 
  `db.execute('PRAGMA user_version = 2');`
- Check version before accessing table: 
  `db.execute('PRAGMA user_version');`

Another way:
Copy DB and Rename DB place it in same place in Code use new DB name. Ti.Database.open('newDBName'). This is not a good approach.

```
var checkDBVersion = function() {
var db = Ti.Database.open(DATABASE_NAME);
var rows = db.execute('PRAGMA user_version');
var dbVersion = 0;
if (rows.isValidRow()) {
    dbVersion = rows.fieldByName('user_version');
}
db.close();
return dbVersion;};
```

Declare your Current DB version like var DBVersion = 2.

```
if(DBVersion!=checkDBVersion()){ //Write your alter query for Table }
```

Whenever your application DB changes for further release of application need to update your DBVersion variable.

Comment: Hi Venkatesh, How can I check from titanium code about current DB version of sqlite and based on that ALTER table ?? If possible can you provide some lines of code. ? Thank You

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check this may be useful to you.